# SQL Server : query get most school with composer songs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got these three tables:

```
create table musicSchool 
(
    schoolId numeric(2)  not null,
    name     varchar(30) not null,
    city     varchar(20) not null
)

create table Composer
(
    composerId numeric(4)  not null,
    name       varchar(20) not null,
    birthday   datetime    null,
    schoolId   numeric(2)  null
)

create table Song 
(
    songnumber numeric(5)  not null,
    composerId numeric(4)  not null,
    title      varchar(20) not null,
    year       numeric(4)  not null
)
```

Now I want the school or schools with the most composer songs.

```
SELECT 
    M.name, COUNT(M.name)
FROM
    musicSchool M 
INNER JOIN
    Composer C ON M.schoolId = C.schoolId
INNER JOIN
    Song S ON C.composerId= S.composerId
GROUP BY 
    M.name
```

I get the schools with their total number of composer songs but i want the school/schools with the highest number of composer songs.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is a basic join exercise. There is not need for exists and subqueries here. Just inner joins and basic aggregation. Hint, look at COUNT.

Comment: apply join between table Composer and song and then check it by "any"  from your musicSchool table

Comment: At first glance, this appears to be a "relational division" problem. Do a google search for SQL Server Relational Division... https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+relational+division&rlz=1C1ASUC_enUS560US561&oq=sql+server+relational+division&aqs=chrome..69i57.7575j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you use TOP to get only the topmost records.

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES
    M.name, COUNT(M.name) as SongCount
FROM
    musicSchool M 
INNER JOIN
    Composer C ON M.schoolId = C.schoolId
INNER JOIN
    Song S ON C.composerId= S.composerId
GROUP BY 
    M.name
ORDER BY SongCount DESC
```

Comment: i always forget about with ties. +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

Simple way with a cte and derived table.

```
with cte as(
    SELECT
        M.name, 
        CT = COUNT(s.songnumber)
    FROM
        musicSchool M 
    INNER JOIN
        Composer C ON M.schoolId = C.schoolId
    INNER JOIN
        Song S ON C.composerId= S.composerId
    GROUP BY 
        M.name)

select c.*
from cte c
inner join
    (select CT = max(ct) from cte) c2 on c2.CT = c.CT
```